# Angular display message if list is empty

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I'm displaying subwebs that the current user has access to, in a sharepoint app part.

I've managed to hide or show a message saying "There is no sites avaiable for you" if my app.js returns 0 in the scope.array.

BUT, the message is displaying before the list has finished loading and when the list has loaded the message dissapears. How can I fix that?

I have a ng-repeat in a table with textbox for filtering:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text" placeholder="Filter..." />

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Site
                </th>
                <th>
                    Created
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="site in sites | filter:text">
            <tr>
                <td>
                  {{site.title}}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {{site.created | date:dateFormat}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div ng-show="!(sites| filter:text).length">There is no sites avaiable for you.</div>
</div>
```

I understand that the ng-show is outside the table where ng-repeat is executed, but I've tried inserting the ng-show div inside the tbody but then if no sites exist the table is never executed.

Also, how can I disable the filter textbox if the array is empty? Tried the same attributes as ng-show but in ng-disabled, but that doesnt work.

Answer (score 3):

Wait for your success callback to determine there are no results before showing the message.

```
//view
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-show="loading">Loading..</div>
  <input ng-hide="noSites" ng-model="text" placeholder="Filter...">
  //table ..
  <div ng-show="noSites">
    There are no sites available for you.
  </div>
</div>

//controller
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    //initialize
    $scope.loading = true
    $scope.noSites = false

    //sharepoint code to get sites
    .success(function(data) {
      if (data.length != 0) {
        $scope.sites = data
      } else {
        $scope.noSites = true
      }
      $scope.loading = false
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text" placeholder="Filter..." />
```

put this inside the `<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">..` div

and modify this

```
<div ng-show="!sites.length" style="display:none">There is no sites avaiable for you.</div> // added `display:none
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now I just need help with the text displaying to the users if the array is empty. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: Hmm. Now, if the array is empty the div ng-show doesnt show, because style is display:none?

Comment: try `ng-style="display:none"` instead `style="display:none"`

Comment: Still showing before the list finished loading, but now it works if the array doesn't have any value. I have to put this div tag AFTER the list loaded, but it's loading the div (that's last in order) before the list??